# XmlAdaptar in JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2, moxy

I have the following `Enum` Class:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = PastMedicalHistoryAdapter.class)
public enum PastMedicalHistory {
    Diabetes, Obesity, Smoking, COPD, CAD, PVD, Other
}
```

and Generic Adapter:

```
public abstract class GenericEnumAdapter<T extends Enum> extends XmlAdapter<String, Enum> {

    @Override
    public Enum unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        log.info("unmarshal: {}", v);
        return convert(v + "");
    }

    public abstract T convert(String value);

    @Override
    public String marshal(Enum v) throws Exception {
        log.info("marshal: {}", v.name());
        String s = "{\"" + v.name() + "\":" + true + "}";
        return s;
    }
}
```

and basic implementation with

```
public class PastMedicalHistoryAdapter extends GenericEnumAdapter<PastMedicalHistory> {
    @Override
    public PastMedicalHistory convert(String value) {
        return PastMedicalHistory.valueOf(value);
    }
}
```

and I used it like this:

```
@Data
@XmlRootElement(name = "Patient")
public class Test {

    private List<PastMedicalHistory> history;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext cxt = JAXBContext.newInstance(Test.class);
        Marshaller mar = cxt.createMarshaller();
        mar.setProperty(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        mar.setProperty(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        mar.setProperty(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, Boolean.FALSE);
        Test t = new Test();
        t.setHistory(Arrays.asList(PastMedicalHistory.CAD, PastMedicalHistory.Diabetes));
        mar.marshal(t, System.out);
    }
}
```

the problem, is Output for history is always null like this:

```
[exec:exec]
2013-09-29 12:13:18:511 INFO marshal: CAD
2013-09-29 12:13:18:522 INFO marshal: Diabetes
{
   "history" : [ null, null ]
}
```

I'm using Moxy `2.5.1` as `JAXB` Provider, so What I'm missing, or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [JAXB (JSR-222)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

I have been able to reproduce the bug that you are hitting.  You can use the following link to track our progress on this issue:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/418486